# Getting error information when executing recovery scenario

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

First what I need to accomplish... 
If the test fails it leaves a web browser open and I need to close it. I cannot just close iexplore.exe as there might be other browser windows opened that I want to leave opened.

Now...
I have a recovery scenario that fires on any error in test execution where I close the specific browser window. When the test fails it fires up and closes the browser. Excellent. The problem is that the test is marked as passed. I can fail it using reporter.reportevent, but I still miss the data about the error.

If I disable the recovery scenario the test fails, correctly, and I have a bunch of information about why the test failed. Is it possible to have that information passed to the recovery scenario? So I could close the browser, fail the test AND have the information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your test is failing.  Recovery Scenarios are great for handling completely unpredictable situations - like the browser window completely crashing at an unpredictable time, or the network connecting dropping for whatever reason, or worse, some nag screen appears offering to upgrade you to the latest operating system and takes over the screen...

If your script is failing at a predictable point, such that you can sprinkle in IF statements that check to make sure your next step is viable (i.e. check if button.exists), then you don't need to rely on the recovery scenario - you would start the fail test process directly.

Here's what I do - I have a function called FailTestBecause() that takes one parameter - a string containing the reason for failure (I know the reason because of the if statement that wraps the call to this function)

FailTestBecause() first sets a flag indicating failure, logs the failure message to reporter, the log, and to my own error file, then attempt to fire an action called "Finish Test".  If action: Finish Test doesn't exist, then gracefully exits using Exittest().

FinishTest is the last action in my test, and when it starts, it checks for the error flag.  either way, it's job is to upload any remaining files back to QC/ALM.  This way, I always get my test data gathered up and uploaded to QC before the script actually stops.

My code is liberally sprinkled with failure checks.  here's an example...

```
Browser("Trade").Page("Login Page").WebEdit("User ID").Set User_ID
Browser("Trade").Page("Login Page").WebEdit("Password").SetSecure User_Password
Browser("Trade").Page("Login Page").WebButton("Login").Click

Do Until Browser("Trade").Page("Main Page").Exist(0)
  If Browser("Trade").Page("Login Page").WebElement("Login Failed").Exist(0) then 
    FailTestBecause "Login Failed, user credentials didn't work"
  ElseIf Browser("Trade").Page("Challenge Questions").Exist(0) then
    say "Found Challenge Questions Screen, handling it..."
    RunAction "Handle Challenge Questions", OneIteration
  ElseIF Browser("Trade").Page("Create Password").Exist(0) then
    FailTestBecause "Detected new password, requires manual change"
  ElseIf not Browser("Trade").Exist(0) then
    FailTestBecause "Browser page crashed?"
  Else
    FailTestBecause "Something (unhandled) went wrong, please review log"
  End If
Loop
```

Check for failure often.  We are testers, after all.

Comment: The trick is that I want to be sure the browser I have opened at the beginning of the test is closed at the end, even if the test fails for any reason. I could wrap everything in conditional statements but I am trying to keep things as simple as possible and have all the logic, or most of it at least, not in the scripts themselves. Recovery scenario seems like a good thing if I only knew how to work them...

Comment: To be clear, I don't USUALLY "wrap everything in conditionals"...  I just always put a .exist check in for specific controls before assuming its safe to start entering data into the UAT.  That allows me to control UAT failures on my own.

Comment: I dug deep into how Recovery Scenarios work (in the documentation) and the biggest issue I see with using recovery scenarios is that: after the recovery scenario completes, it wants to either A) continue execution near where it left off, B) continue to next action or iteration, C) restart the whole test, or D) exit.   This means that to do what you want to do, you will need to process all of the post-problem processing (collect crash data, report it, etc) all within the recovery scenario itself, and then let it end the test.  There doesn't seem to be an option to "continue from point X".

Comment: Cheers for the effort. Also I'm not saying using conditionals is bad, I use them also, it just doesn't fully solve my problem here. After the recovery scenario for test error fires up it ends the test which is fine by me as I don't need to continue with the test. The problem is with post-problem processing, is the info about the error lost when recovery scenario fires up? Hard to believe. Well, I might have to do this try catch style as a workaround...

Comment: One of the things you can do during a recovery scenario is to call a function... You should be able to gather the information you need within that function before the recovery scenario ends the test...